# Google Sheets API - How to get repeating column number?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I want to update my google docs spreadsheet using API.

I have the following table

[image]

Is it possible to make query to insert value in D3 without mentioning exact coordinate ? The problem is that I have about 10 repeating sections and sometimes they can be changed, so I need a way to find range of, for example, section two and then find coordinate of column with `name` inside of section two.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with [Google Apps Script for Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets).

The flow I'd go at it would probably be something like:

1. Get all top row values (e.g. `Section One`, `Section Two`, and so on).
2. Identify the values where value is `Name`.
3. Proceed with what else you need.

<sub>With that said, I'm sure you're well aware (seeing as you're a *well-rep* user :) ) that asking for codes or anything similar is off-topic or could be considered too broad here in Stack Overflow.</sub>